# Prove that the Cartesian product of the natural and rational numbers is countably infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is countably infinite.
I understand that I somehow have to show that a bijection exists between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q}$, I’m just struggling to see a way of labelling the set in such a way that no elements are missed.

Comment: Are you familiar with a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Try to prove that $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{N} \sim \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Besides, what has your question to do with `combinatorics`?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur by representing the rationals in a grid you can label them to create a surjection, proving that $|\mathbb{Q}|\leq|\mathbb{N}|$. This proves a bijection exists, correct?

Comment: Actually it suffices to show that injections exist both ways, and then invoke Schröder-Bernstein.